# How to close a window/program with matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am opening some files outside matlab with the command **winopen(filename)**.
is there some way to close the program/window with a matlab command? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1XQ4UF/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1XQ4UF) technical note

> There is no built-in feature in MATLAB 7.1 (R14SP3) that would enable you to close documents once they have been opened using WINOPEN.

So unless they added it in the latest version I don't think it is possible.